# Tracking an e-commerce conversion with Google Analytics - Analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, ruby-on-rails, event-tracking

I'm running a Rails (`Ruby on Rails`) app and want to start collecting e-commerce conversion data. I have Google Analytics installed on a local server (development environment), and I am able to see the data from local visits (aliased / tunneled `localhost:3000`), and track real-time Goal Conversions just fine. However, I am not able to see any e-comm conversions. Here is what the rendered JS snippet looks like:

```
<script>
 ... 
 // tacking code
 // ga(create)
 ...

  ga('send', 'pageview');

  ga('require', 'ecommerce'); 
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id'            : '298',
    'affiliation'   : 'Tax',
    'revenue'       : '0.0',
    'shipping'      : '0.0',
    'tax'           : '0.0'
  });
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id'      : '227',
    'sku'     : '227',
    'name'    : 'Alpha 0 featured listing',
    'category': 'Appliances',
    'price'   : '23.34',
    'quantity': '1'
  });
  ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

The `ecommerce` object calls are added on the `thank-you` page. Otherwise, only the `pageView` event gets sent. Am I doing it wrong by combining `addItem` and `addTransaction`?

#### EDIT:

I am able to see both `hitType` vars being sent up via `google_analytics_debug.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Google analytics Admin page and check if your VIEW(s) has ecommerce enabled (Set to ON). Also make sure you have created a Goal to track conversion to that "thank you" Page.

If you use a destination goal to the "thank you" page remember to leave the goal Value field blank.

Comment: got the e-comm enabled. Did not know that I need to couple the e-comm tracking with a goal. Trying this now. Thanks!

Comment: still not seeing a conversion. I added a goal with a funnel and was able to verify it with conversion rate approximation. Maybe its because I'm running in development?

Comment: ok, turned out to be the 24-hour delay in data processing, which is weird since I'm running the server locally. Thanks for your help!